# use pexpect under subprocess had error

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I use `pexpect`'s `pxssh` model wrote an auto ssh login program.
but when i use the same program in `multiprocessing`, this error occurs:

```
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/zenoss/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 525, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/zenoss/lib/python2.6/threading.py", line 477, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/zenoss/lib/python2.6/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 259, in _handle_results
    task = get()
TypeError: ('__init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)', <class 'pexpect.EOF'>, ())
```

### this is my code:

```
import pxssh
import multiprocessing

class ssh_linux:
    def __init__(self,q_host,linux_user,linux_pwd,linux_su_passwd,linux_port):
        timeout=5
        status,shell=self.ssh_login(q_host,linux_user,linux_pwd,timeout,linux_port)
        #i think this error--------
        if status:
            print 'conn ok!'
            self.set_env(shell)

    def ssh_login(self,q_host,linux_user,linux_pwd,timeout,linux_port):
        status=0
        try:
            s = pxssh.pxssh()
            s.login (q_host,linux_user,linux_pwd,port=linux_port,auto_prompt_reset=True,login_timeout=timeout)
            status=1
        except pxssh.ExceptionPxssh, e:
            s=str(e)
            print "ssh login fail!",s
            status=0
        return status,s

def do_calculation(data):
    run=ssh_linux(q_host,linux_user,linux_pwd,linux_su_passwd,linux_port)

def main():     
    pool_size = multiprocessing.cpu_count() * 2
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=pool_size,initializer=start_process,)
    pool.map(do_calculation,input_list)
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

Comment: Where's the code that you wrote?

Comment: the error says it all, `__init__` takes 2 arguments one is self, and other you have to pass, while instantiating

Answer (score 1):

thanks everyone.
I found solve this.

this problem is my:**Code does not regulate**
I change my code to this,the return is OK:

```
    self.hostname = q_host
    self.username = linux_user
    self.password = linux_pwd
    self.su_pw=linux_su_passwd
    self.port=linux_port
    status,shell=self.ssh_login(self.hostname,self.username,self.password,self.timeout,self.port)
```